# POST extra values in an HTML <form>

Tags: html, post, forms, http-post

I have a simple form which passes the value of an `<input />` element:

```
<form action="updaterow.php" method="POST"> 
    <input type="text" name="price" />
</form>
```

How can I post extra values along with the `<input />` value? For example, an arbitrary string, or a variable inside the current PHP script.

I know this is possible with GET:

```
<form action="updaterow.php?foo=bar" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="price" />
</form>
```

or:

```php
<form action="updaterow.php?foo=<?=htmlspecialchars($bar)?>" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="price" />
</form>
```

but I need POST.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can include a hidden form element.

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
```

Comment: is having hidden elements a bad practice at all?

Comment: @Abdul No. In fact, it's the only way to solve this particular problem!

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use a [hidden field](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_hidden.asp). Like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="your-field-name" value="your-field-value" />
```

This field will then be available in your PHP script as `$_POST['your-field-name']`

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned already, using hidden input fields is an option, but you can also use a [session](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). That way you don´t have to post anything, the variables remain on the server and are not exposed in the html.