# Pass additional data with submit button

Tags: html, asp.net-core

I have form, with two buttons:

```html
 <form action="/Book/Crud" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="bookInput" />  
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
        <button type="submit">Save and exit</button>
    </form>
```

How can I pass to my controller, or, whatever, additional value, which depends on button?
`<button type="submit" ?????? >Save</button>` What should be here?

I am using Asp.Net Core, with this controller:

```
public IActionResult Crud(string bookInput)
{
    //removed code for brevity
}
```

Comment: Please add more information; add backend (C#, Wordpress, "IDontKnow"), what controller? what server? etc etc

Comment: @Leon edited question.

Comment: Related: [php/html form post extra values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4598779/php-html-form-post-extra-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use jquery to solve the issue:

**cshtml**

```
<form action="/Book/Crud" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="bookInput" />  
        <button type="submit" name="Submit">Save</button>
        <button type="submit" name="SubmitAndExit">Save and exit</button>
</form>
```

**jquery**

```
$("form").submit(function () {
     var btn = $(this).find("input[type=submit]:focus" );
     var btnName = btn.attr('name');
     var input = $("<input>")
           .attr("name", "btnName").val(btnName);
     $(this).append(input);
     return true;
});
```

Comment: That's the answer, the only remark is that `"button[type=submit]:focus"` instead of `"input[type=submit]:focus"`.

Comment: Also, what should we do with created nameless input?

Answer (score 4):

```
<form action="/Book/Crud" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="bookInput" />  
    <button name="action" value="save" type="submit">Save</button>
    <button name="action" value="save-exit" type="submit">Save and exit</button>
</form>
```

Like other inputs, the button can have a `name` and `value` attribute which will be submitted to your backend on submit. Only the button that was clicked will send its value. You need to use whatever mechanism you're using to access the POSTed variable named `action` (in this example). Then just switch on whether it's equal to `save` or `save-exit` and perform the relevant function.

Comment: The same question: how can I catch difference between those two buttons on server side?

Comment: @YuriyN. Look at the value of the POSTed variable named action. If it's "save", the "Save" button was pressed. If it's "save-exit", the "Save and exit" button was pressed.

Comment: I'm not sure how can I do this at ASP.NET Core, could you explain please?

Comment: I don't know asp.net, I'm afraid. Are you not already processing the 'bookInput' value? It should be the exact same procedure.

Comment: Yes, it is already processed, but this processing is already built-in ASP.NET Core, about processing `button`'s value, I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm sure you'll be able to find the answer to "How do I access a POST variable in asp.net" on this site. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360956/how-to-get-post-and-get-data-from-a-form-in-asp-net

Answer (score 4):

The answer of Bobby Jack is correct. I will elaborate on this answer in order to show how to access this input from within the controller. If you would use the following HTML:

```
<form action="/Book/Crud" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="bookInput" />  
    <button name="action" value="save" type="submit">Save</button>
    <button name="action" value="save-exit" type="submit">Save and exit</button>
</form>
```

You could reach the values: 'save' and 'save-exit' by defining another parameter in the controller like this:

```
// The parameter 'action' is what will contain the values specified in the button.
public IActionResult Crud(string bookInput, string action)
{
    // Implementation
}
```

The name of the parameter needs to correspond to the value in the 'name' attribute of the form button (in this case 'action'). When the button is clicked, ASP.net will automatically assign the value of the 'value' attribute to the controller parameter. Or more specifically the controller parameter 'action' will have a value of 'save' or 'save-exit' retrieved from the attribute 'value'.

Answer (score 0):

add different names

```
<button type="submit" name="save">Save</button>
<button type="submit" name="saveExit">Save and exit</button>
```

Comment: And how can I catch difference between this buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Example from VB.net:

```
<asp:Button id="cmdKeyphraseAdd" runat="server" Text="Add Keyphrase" onclick="cmdKeyphraseAdd_Click"></asp:Button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
 <form action="/Book/Crud" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="bookInput" />  
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
        <button type="submit">Save and exit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).